# Excel VBA Array (3d) Novice

Tags: excel, vba, populate, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to populate a 3d array and (at this point) simply return it in msgbox, the data I want in the array is in colums 9, 15 and 16 and would be like...

2342341234, 01/01/1969, 18:00

I keep getting a type mismatch and cannot fathom why, please help if you can, all suggestions welcome as I'm a novice at this stuff

```
Option Explicit
Global NumberOfRows As Integer
Global FirstRowOfData As Integer
Global LastRowOfData As Integer
Global i As Integer 'row loop
Global HospNo() As Integer
Global TRCDate() As Date
Global TRCTime() As Date
Global MonthArray(HospNo, TRCDate, TRCTime)


Sub CreateMonthArray()

    FirstRowOfData = 1

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRowOfData = Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A65535").End(xlUp)).Count
    End With

    Dim MonthArray(HospNo, TRCDate, TRCTime)

    For i = FirstRowOfData To NumberOfRows

        Let MonthArray(HospNo) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 9).value)
        Let MonthArray(TRCDate) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 15).value)
        Let MonthArray(TRCTime) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 16).value)

    MsgBox MonthArray(HospNo(i), TRCDate(i), TRCTime(i))

    Next i

End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What line gives you that error?  Read about declaring arrays in VBA Help.  Also you have duplicate declarations for MonthArray in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full discussion of how to create and populate a 3D array of these values, rather just pointing out where your errors are in the code you have presented, which is just creating a single line.

I suspect your error comes on the Global or Dim MonthArray statements.  In VBA, Arrays don't have "named" arguments.  If that is the issue, you might try something like:

```
Global MonthArray(0 to 2) as Variant
```

and then, in your code:

```
MonthArray(0) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 9).value)
MonthArray(1) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 15).value)
MonthArray(2) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 16).value)
```

If you want to use Named Arguments (which can be real convenient for debugging, you probably should define a Class object.

In VBA, I usually use Public and not Global; and you should eliminate your duplicate declaration of MonthArray in the body of your code.  Also, the Let statement is optional.

You also need to ensure that your NumberOfRows variable is set to a value somewhere.  It is not set to anything within this module but, since it is a Public variable, you might be setting it elsewhere.

Finally, your MsgBox statement should be accessing the data in MonthArray by the index number.  EG:

```
MsgBox MonthArray(0) & ", " &  MonthArray(1) & "m " & MonthArray(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ron, I can't tell you how long I spent trying to get that working without humiliating myself here.  I'd upvote this if I could... With your notes, the working code is below

```
Option Explicit
Public NumberOfRows As Integer
Public FirstRowOfData As Integer
Public LastRowOfData As Integer
Public i As Integer 'row loop
'Public HospNo() As Integer
'Public TRCDate() As Date
'Public TRCTime() As Date
Public MonthArray(0 To 2) As Variant


Sub CreateMonthArray()

    FirstRowOfData = 1

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRowOfData = Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A65535").End(xlUp)).Count
    End With

    'Dim MonthArray(HospNo, TRCDate, TRCTime)

    For i = FirstRowOfData To LastRowOfData

         MonthArray(0) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 9).value)
         MonthArray(1) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 15).value)
         MonthArray(2) = (ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 16).value)

    MsgBox MonthArray(0) & ", " & MonthArray(1) & ", " & MonthArray(2)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Some of what I think you might have been trying to do can be enabled by Classes.  See [Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx) discussion by Chip Pearson for an introduction.